# Updating access token for sharepoint "@SSL\DavWWWRoot" without IE?

Tags: python, sharepoint

We are using "@SSL\DavWWWRoot" addresses to move files to SharePoint. We have used IE to update the access token, after which we have been able to move files using the webdav address and python.

Our company has now removed IE from all computers and we have not been able to refresh access tokens using Edge. How can I update the access token without internet explorer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @community Thanks for the feedback mr. Bot. I have reformatted the question to not trigger your automatic answer.